# How should I present myself as a master graduate?

Tags: formulation-idiomatique, éducation

How should I present myself when I want to introduce myself as a master graduate. How should I say such a sentence in french language?
Can I use the both verbs "être" and "avoir" in this case or not?
  "I have a M.A.(master) in urban planning from Allameh University."

Answer (score 3):

Une proposition supplémentaire:

> Je suis titulaire d'un master en urbanisme obtenu (avec les honneurs) à l'université d'Allameh.

Comment: Différence régionale à noter: au Canada, ce diplôme est appelé une maîtrise ([e.g.](https://www.usherbrooke.ca/gmecanique/futurs-etudiants/aux-cycles-superieurs/futurs-etudiants-2e-cycle/quoi/))

Answer (score 1):

Il y a toute une variété de possibilités assez formelles parmi lesquelles choisir. En voilà quatre.

- Je suis diplomé(e) en urbanisme de l'université Allameh, de laquelle je **détiens** un diplôme de master( dans cette dicipline).
- Je **détiens** un diplôme de master en urbanisme de l'université Allameh.
- Mes études en urbanisme à l'université Allameh **se sont conclues** par un diplôme de master( dans cette discipline).
- À la fin de mes études en urbanisme à l'université Allameh m'a été **accordé** un diplôme de master( dans cette discipline).

Dans le contexte formel d'un CV  et autres écrits similaires il vaut mieux  éviter les formules simples telles que « J'ai un master… » et « Je suis master en… ».

Comment: I think you've correctly deduced (from the use of "present [myself]" and "introduce [myself]") that OP is looking for formal options (and you've covered those nicely, imo), but for more casual exchanges (small talk in a French bar, for example), do you think something like "J'ai l'équivalent d'un Bac plus 4 (ou 5) en urbanisme de l'université Allameh" would still work (if it ever would have)? Thanks.

Comment: @PapaPoule Il me semble difficile de le dire différemment! …dans la langue parlée et même formellement ; ce serait une forme passe-partout. Il me semble d'ailleurs avoir entendu maintes fois cela exprimé de cette façon  sans jamais avoir eu le besoin d'y substituer une autre forme .

Answer (score 1):

1. J'ai un degré/diplôme troisième cycle en physique (votre sujet).
2. Je suis un post-diplômé en physique.
3. J'ai un master en physique.